# Is there a way to limit the number of messages/second the client is sending in a Python chatroom application?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, spam-prevention, chatroom

I am making a python chatroom application for school with a functioning clientside and serverside script. I am now adding multiple functionalities to the chatroom to make it easier to use, one of which is hopefully spam protection. Is there a way I can record how many messages per a certain measurement of time the client is sending and if they go over the maximum they are muted for a certain amount of time?

clientside.py:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tkinter
#import tkinter.ttk as ttk
#from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from tkinter import END
from datetime import *
import time as tme
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, '[' + current_time + '] ' + msg)
            msg_list.yview(END)
            msg_list.yview()
        except OSError:
            break
def send(event=None):
    msg = my_msg.get()
    if msg.isspace() != True:
        my_msg.set("")
        client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
        msg_list.yview(END)
        msg_list.yview()
    elif msg.isspace() == True:
        my_msg.set("")
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()
def on_closing(event=None):
    top.destroy()
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()
    top.quit()
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
#top.iconbitmap('C:/Users/Ethen Dixon/Downloads/filled_chat_aH2_icon.ico')
top.title("Chat Room 90")
#style = ThemedStyle(top)
#style.set_theme("equilux")
messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
my_msg.set("[type here]")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=30, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg, width=100)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()
top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

HOST = input('Enter host: ')
PORT = input('Enter port: ')
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)
receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

serverside.py:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        client.send(bytes("Welcome to Chat Room 90! Please type in your username and press enter.", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()
def handle_client(client):
    """Handles a single client connection."""
    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    welcome = 'Welcome %s!' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
            broadcast(msg, name+": ")
        else:
            client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
            break
def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    """Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)
clients = {}
addresses = {}
HOST = ''
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

Comment: Yes, there are ways of doing that. What were you thinking you might try?

Comment: something to do with time.sleep(x) but after trying that it just slowed the application and the messages sent anyway

Comment: Can you just drop messages?

Comment: Presumably any limit that was implemented on the client side could be removed by the user in order to defeat the limit; a better approach would be to install rate-limiting logic on the server side, e.g. add the incoming messages to the tail of a FIFO queue and only pop them from the head of the queue (to forward to the other clients) at a maximum rate of 1 per second or whatnot.   (Don't forget to limit the size of the FIFO queue to a reasonable maximum so that a mischevious user can't use it to fill up your server's RAM)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is using the `widget.unbind(sequence, funcid = None)` method.
This, as the name suggests, deletes the bindings on w for a determined event.

Then you can use the tkinter built-in method `root.after()` to call a function that you create to rebind the button to the function.

But for this to work you need to bind the send_button using the `.bind()` method.

```
def rebind():
     send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
     
send_button.bind("<Button-1>", send)
send_button.unbind("<Button-1>", funcid=None) 
top.after(time in miliseconds, rebind)
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete the command when creating the button